# O que é um Modelo de Memória?

Tags: java, multithreading, c++11, concorrência

Lendo [o artigo da Wikipedia em Inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)) descobri que Java foi a primeira linguagem popular a ter um modelo de memória na presença de threads bem definido, seguido do C++11.

Lendo o artigo em questão me parece que o modelo de memória define regras e garantias sobre como a linguagem deve de comportar quando múltiplas *threads* lêem e escrevem em variáveis potencialmente compartilhadas. Em especial, o Modelo de Memória parece definir regras para a ordem das operações, bem como sobre a visibilidade de mudanças em memória compartilhada. Conforme o artigo, o modelo de memória abre espaço para otimizações que normalmente não seriam possíveis em um ambiente *multi-threaded*.

Apesar de ter entendido de maneira rasa para que serve um modelo de memória eu não entendi direito o que ele é. Que tipos de regras são definidas em um modelo de memória? E como isso é implementado na prática? (O artigo fala muito de [*memory barriers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)) e [*fences*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) que também são conceitos novos para mim).

Comment: Parte da minha iniciativa para trazer perguntas para a comunidade

Comment: Esse artigo é bem antigo, mas excelente para entender inclusive a questão de objetos imutáveis e  o problema que eles causam no JMM (Java Memory Model) https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02244/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Um modelo de memória é uma especificação que define como os threads se comportam ao acessar e modificar dados compartilhados na memória. Inclui regras sobre a ordem das operações e a visibilidade das alterações na memória compartilhada.

As regras definidas no modelo de memória incluem, por exemplo, quando as threads podem ler ou escrever variáveis ​​compartilhadas e qual thread tem prioridade sobre outra thread ao acessar a mesma variável. Ele também define quando um thread pode ver as alterações feitas em uma variável compartilhada por outro thread.

Uma das formas de implementar essas regras é através de "barreiras de memória" e "limites" (cercas). As barreiras de memória são mecanismos que garantem que certas operações sejam concluídas antes que outras operações possam ocorrer. Por exemplo, as barreiras de memória podem garantir que um thread só possa ler uma variável compartilhada depois que outro thread tiver gravado nela. Os limites são um mecanismo de ordem de operação que garante que as operações sejam executadas na ordem especificada.

Além disso, o modelo de memória também pode incluir mecanismos para garantir a sincronização entre as threads, como locks e semáforos, que permitem que uma thread bloqueie o acesso a um determinado trecho de código até que ele seja liberado.

A implementação de um modelo de memória é uma tarefa complexa que requer cuidados para garantir um código multi-thread seguro e correto. A linguagem Java fornece mecanismos integrados como volátil, sincronizado e atômico para ajudar a implementar o modelo de memória, mas é importante entender as limitações e implicações de cada um.

Você pode ler mais sobre nesse site: https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).